# How do I convert a sequence of images into a movie that the filename does not start from 1?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, movie

I have a sequence of images to be converted into a movie. The only problem is that, I wanted to start converting image number 120 until 240 into a movie using ffmpeg but I don't know the command line for that. Is there any possible command line for this kind of case?

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed frames using php-ffmpeg api and  then converted it into move. Here is a sample code which shows how to grab frames

```
@$mov = new ffmpeg_movie($video_file_name);
if($mov->getFrameCount() > 1000) {
     //grab frames and make movie
}
```